# VSTS Release Management Continuous Deployment not working

Tags: azure-devops, tfsbuild, ms-release-management, azure-pipelines

I am using Visual Studio Team Services for my Builds and Releases. I followed Microsoft's documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vs/alm/release/author-release-definition/more-release-definition#triggers) to set up my release definition to deploy every time a linked build is created (Continuous Deployment). However the trigger is not working.

My build definition simply follows the steps bellow:

- NuGet Installer
- Visual Studio Build
- Copy and Publish Build Artifacts

My release definition's trigger is set up as Continuous Deployment and pointing to my release definition. The environment is set up with "Automated: after release creation"

My build completes successfully but the release is never triggered. I can kick of the release manually and it works fine. I would like the release to launch immediately from the build. Any ideas why this is not working?

Comment: Can you send us an email to rm_customer_queries_at_microsoft_dot_com? We would like to get some more details to understand this problem. Once resolved, I will post the details here.

Comment: Does it work if you create a new release and build definition?

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT I created a new build and release and it did not work.

Comment: Can you share the screenshot for the settings in "Artifacts" and "Triggers" tab of your release definition?

Comment: And another thing to check: Expand the context menu of your release definition and select "Security...", check if the "Create Releases" permission for those groups/users is set to "Allow".

Comment: I work with @Dan and this appears to be a issue related to the specific account of VSTS. If either of us do the same steps in a personal VSTS account it works as expected. commit->build->release. It will not work in the work account. I have added myself explicitly in security as well as having a TFS admin commit and trigger the pipeline. Nothing works.

Comment: @Grummle Then you can submit an issue on Microsoft Connect Page: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Feedback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There wound up being a Db entry problem with our VSTS account. This was fixed by the rm_customer_queries_at_microsoft_dot_com team.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps I would take to troubleshoot your problem:

1. Double click on one of your successful builds and download the log file. At the bottom of the log file you will see where your build was published.  Does it show that you have your artifacts in your build? Is there anything highlighted in yellow?
2. Do you have your release definition linked to your build?
3. Is the path to your web deployment package associated with your build?

When I was first setting things up, I had the same problem and this is what I did to fix it:

On the build solutions section of your build , be sure that your MS Build is set to: /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true

On your CopyFiles section be sure you have your contents going to a zip folder: 
***zip

On your release definition, be sure your Web Deploy package is pointing at that zip file:  $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)***.zip

Comment: Are you talking about the new VSTS Release management (node) or the older one based on XAML?